# Machine name set to new-host-X instead of the name set in Preferences

Tags: macos, network

My machine name is set `shiny` in System Preferences/Sharing/Computer Name.

From another machine on the network, I can only use `shiny.local` to refer to this machine. In the past, I used only `shiny`.

In a terminal, I have `new-host-7` instead of the machine name.

I don't know if this is relevant, but the computers are connected to an internet box, on which a DHCP server is activated. I assigned a static IP address to the Mac. The internet box can see the name I gave to the Mac.

Is there something I can do to refer to the Mac as `shiny` on the network ?

Comment: Sounds like the DHCP server assigns the name...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sudo scutil --set HostName shiny` and `sudo scutil --set LocalHostName shiny` then close your shell (Terminal window) and open a new one.

Comment: It's working locally. I'm using two interfaces on the Mac, but one of them if down(Wifi) at home. Other machines keep on thinking shiny's Wifi address is still valid though.

Comment: That sounds more like a DNS issue; are you running any kind of local DNS service, even if only in your router?  If you open your Sharing prefpane and click Edit under Computer Name, do you have dynamic global hostname enabled?

Comment: No, it's not enabled. Should it ? There is only a DNS service in the router.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out here - (the scutil command is nice to know but didn't work)

Access your router (usually 192.168.1.1 or something) and look for the list of devices. On my Verizon Router this is under "My Network." You should be able to rename them there.

The problem I found was that my computer had two *different* IP connections to the router: one was the ethernet, the other was the wireless connection. The wireless connection had the correct name, the other one had "new-host-5". You can't have the same name for both, so rename the wireless connection to whatever, and then change the name of the ethernet connection to what you want. (Also I just disabled the Wireless connection, because I don't need both... Don't know if that was necessary though)
Hope This helps!