# Terminal showing 192 instead of computername

Tags: macos, terminal, network, xcode

I have a situation in which sometimes when I launch Terminal instead of showing:

```
computername:~ user$
```

It instead shows:

```
192:~ user$
```

I've already found that the questions [OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/201104) and  [Machine name set to new-host-X instead of the name set in Preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/56048) are both very closely related to mine. However the solutions placed the origin of the 'problem' at using Xcode or a double internet connection (Wi-Fi + wired).

I have Xcode installed but haven't used it for quite some time. Also, I'm only using a Wi-Fi connection.

So, what could cause Terminal to sometimes display my computername correctly and sometimes only display `192` instead of it?

Comment: i think the listing of your computer name is set in the .bash_profile file.  Is it possible that .bash_profile had not been run when you get the 192?

Comment: Hmm.. didn't know that .bash_profile was related. How can I check if it ran? Just looked at the contents of the file, in my case it only holds `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` which is apparently put there by Homebrew (At least I guess since the comment `#Homebrew` is written the line above it).

Comment: Sounds like it's NOT used.  I'm obviously wrong about that. Sorry.  I'll keep looking though.

Comment: Have you set your computer name in system preferences/sharing?  I've read that can contribute to your problem.

Comment: Both of the answers you found apply to your case -- it has nothing to do with Xcode or double connections. The solutions are the same: either ignore it (because it doesn't actually matter), or use `sudo scutil --set HostName computernamegoeshere` to override the bogus into the DNS server is handing out.